# Referencing external assemblies from PowerShell snap-in

Tags: c#, powershell, snap-in, pssnapin

I'm developing a custom PowerShell snap-in, which references another project in the solution.
When I try to debug the snap-in (following [these instructions][1]), the assembly fails to load and my cmdlet fails with the message "Could not load file or Assembly..."

How do you instruct PowerShell on how to locate assemblies, or how do you specify where are located the assemblies needed by the snap-in?

I'd prefer to avoid registering the assemblies in the GAC, at least during development.

Comment: cool - glad the solution helped - and this is useful info

Comment: can you re-edit your question to show only the question? then place your answer as an actual answer in the system. It's ok to answer your own question, you know. This would be the best way to use the stackoverflow system. This way others can vote on your answer.

Comment: @halr9000: done. I think you are right about posting the solution among the answers, I don't know about the voting (people could vote the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact behaviour, but I would try and make use of `fuslogvw` to see exactly where the runtime is looking for the problematic assemblies. That would give you a clue as to how to get them to be copied into the correct place on build. [This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=3654c8f3-c5c3-4dee-a01f-c9a8da3ef2fa) by Scott Hanselman is quite useful, and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the official documentation.

If you find the solution, please add an answer, as this must be a common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION (Posting it here as suggested by one of the comments to my question)**

My problem was rather specific, as I'm developing on a 64 bits server machine, but I'm posting the solution in case it could help someone else as well.

Using `fuslogvw` as suggested, I saw that the dependent assembly was being searched using the `machine.config` file under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` and then the binding failed; launching the project with "start without debugging", instead, the `machine.config` file under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` was taken (notice the missing `64` at the end).

I thought that the problem could be due to the image format, and infact the dependent assembly was being compiled with x86 as CPU target; I changed it to "Any CPU" and now the assembly is loaded correctly.