# Powershell Cmdlet Missing Assembly Google Api

Tags: c#, powershell, google-api-dotnet-client

Only have issues when trying to create a Powershell Cmdlet. I can execute the same code in the process record within a console app just fine. Thoughts were the App.config isn't redirecting the assembly but didn't have much success making it work. I used the nuget packages for the references to the Google-api-dotnet-client

**Sample Code here**
http://tinyurl.com/mbx3yle

**Error**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr3zR.png

```
Get-GAppsUsers : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

PsTest.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


namespace PSTest
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]

    public class PsTest : PSSnapIn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specify a description of the PowerShell snap-in.
        /// </summary>
        public override string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return "This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Google Apps Lib";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the localization resource information for the description.
        /// Use the format: resourceBaseName,Description.
        /// </summary>
        public override string DescriptionResource
        {
            get
            {
                return "GoogleAppsPSSnapIn,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Google Apps Lib";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the name of the PowerShell snap-in.
        /// </summary>
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "GoogleApps";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the vendor for the PowerShell snap-in.
        /// </summary>
        public override string Vendor
        {
            get
            {
                return "somecompany";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the localization resource information for the vendor.
        /// Use the format: resourceBaseName,VendorName.
        /// </summary>
        public override string VendorResource
        {
            get
            {
                return "GoogleAppsPSSnapIn,somecompany";
            }
        }
    }

    [Cmdlet("Get", "GAppsUsers")]
    public class GetGAppsUsers : PSCmdlet
    {



        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {

            const string _serviceAccountCertPath = @"C:\cert.p12";
            const string _serviceAccountEmail = @"id@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            const string _serviceAccountUser = @"someone@somewhere.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                _serviceAccountCertPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var scopes = DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryUser.GetStringValue() + @" " +
                         DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryGroup.GetStringValue() + @" " +
                         DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryOrgunit.GetStringValue() + @" " +
                         DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryDeviceChromeos.GetStringValue() + @" " +
                         DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryDeviceMobile.GetStringValue() + @" " +
                         DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryDeviceMobileAction.GetStringValue();

            var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
            {
                ServiceAccountId = _serviceAccountEmail,
                Scope = @scopes
            };

            if (_serviceAccountUser != string.Empty)
            {
                provider.ServiceAccountUser = _serviceAccountUser;
            }

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

            var _directoryService = new DirectoryService((new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = auth }));

            var service = _directoryService.Users.List();

            service.Customer = "my_customer";
            service.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.FamilyName;
            service.SortOrder = UsersResource.ListRequest.SortOrderEnum.ASCENDING;
            service.MaxResults = 500;

            var allUsers = new List<User>();
            var users = service.Execute();

            Int64 count = 0;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(users.NextPageToken))
            {
                service.PageToken = users.NextPageToken;

                allUsers.AddRange(users.UsersValue);

                count = (count + users.UsersValue.Count);

                Console.Write(count + "...");
            }

            while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(users.NextPageToken))
            {
                service.PageToken = users.NextPageToken;

                allUsers.AddRange(users.UsersValue);

                count = (count + users.UsersValue.Count);

                Console.Write(count + "...");
                users = service.Execute();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(users.NextPageToken))
                {
                    service.PageToken = users.NextPageToken;

                    allUsers.AddRange(users.UsersValue);

                    count = (count + users.UsersValue.Count);

                    Console.Write(count + "...");
                }
            }

            WriteObject(allUsers);
        }

    }


}
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <loadfromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Fusion Log

```
    *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/31/2013 @ 8:02:43 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NinjaWinMontage\mosheldon
LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Google.Apis, Version=1.5.0.28972, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\mosheldon\Desktop\PSTest\PSTest\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/31/2013 @ 8:02:43 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NinjaWinMontage\mosheldon
LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Google.Apis, Version=1.5.0.28972, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\mosheldon\Desktop\PSTest\PSTest\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/31/2013 @ 8:08:35 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NinjaWinMontage\mosheldon
LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Google.Apis, Version=1.5.0.28972, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\mosheldon\Desktop\PSTest\PSTest\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/31/2013 @ 8:08:35 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NinjaWinMontage\mosheldon
LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Google.Apis, Version=1.5.0.28972, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\mosheldon\Desktop\PSTest\PSTest\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mosheldon/Desktop/PSTest/PSTest/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.Primitives/System.Net.Http.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Added System.Net.Http.Primitives version 2.1.10 and 1.5 to GAC

```
Get-GAppsUsers : Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_
AutomaticDecompression(System.Net.DecompressionMethods)'.
```

Comment: Can you please post code here so more people can help you?

Comment: Added Sample code in post.

Comment: Use Nuget to install the package Microsoft.Net.Http.

Comment: Use fuslogvw as shown in this SO answer to find out the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542495/referencing-external-assemblies-from-powershell-snap-in

Comment: @KeithHill Microsoft.Net.Http 2.1.10 is installed via Nuget per Google Api DotNet Client

Comment: @Mitul Thanks, I'll give that a shot to find my issue.

Comment: Adding the App.config redirects to the powershell.exe.config and machine.config, same error. Fusion log attached to original post

Comment: check if the assembly is registered in gac or not via gacutil.exe /l in visual studio developer command prompt.

Comment: Version 2.1.10 and 1.5 were not registered in the GAC, registered both with the GAC then received new error, added to top post. The problem would be it's still not redirecting 1.5 to 2.1.10

Comment: Updated the fusion log. This seems to be the main error >
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.

Comment: Did you fixed the problem?

Comment: @Mitul No, the problem still exists. Haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Working through the issue my machine.config had a <runtime/> tag that needed to be removed. I'm working through some more errors now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLUTION

1. **Register the following in GAC (gacutil /i *path of dll*)**

   - System.Net.Http 2.1.10.0
   - System.Net.Http.Primitives 2.1.10.0
   - log4net 1.2.10.0
2. **Add Binding Redirect to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config" (Replace current runtime tag)**

   ```
         <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   ```

Comment: I'm in a very similar boat, but with one question - would this have to be done on every computer that is using the Cmdlets? If so, could this be done programmatically?

Comment: Yes it would have to be done to each, but I believe the issue can be resolved in a better way. Haven't had time to work more on this yet.

Comment: Thanks. I won't pretend to understand what's going on, yet (this is the first time I've heard of the GAC to be honest) but it worked for now. So at least there's that.

Comment: The only reason to use the GAC is because the only other place the "Powershell.exe" process will look for assemblies by default is in its installation directory (c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0).  If you want to avoid the GAC and the machine config mods, you could try implementing  IModuleAssemblyInitializer in your snapin and in the OnImpport hook the current appdomain's AssemblyResolve event.  That will get fired when that appdomain tries to load assemblies it can't find in the usual places (app base dir, GAC).  You can then provide the path to these assemblies (in snapin dir).